# ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

**Connection Code:**

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "USER_NAME", "PASSWORD";
```

**Exception:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the
>   connection with the following error: ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not
>   currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:419)   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:228)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)   at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)

Comment: What is the SID of the database instance?

Comment: do you connect your database with anytool?

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved:**

change 'orcl' in connection string with 'XE'.